# Oracle SQL - convert a varchar2 into a date

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a problem with converting a varchar2 fields into a date format.
I got 2 columns with the datatyp varchar2, one is called qtime the other is called ztime. Both fields contain strings in this format (f.e. 152015 -> would be a timestamp 15:20:15).

For reporting reasons I need to convert this fields into a date format, afterwards I want to substract (qtime-ztime) the fields an convert them into the format [hh] (f.e. after the operation 01:20:00 would be -> 01). Is it possible to to this within Oracle SQL 12c? **The biggest problem for me right now is that I don't get those Strings converted into a date format.**

`select TO_DATE(qtime,'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')` just gives me

> ORA-01861:"literal does not match format string"

`select TO_DATE(qtime,'hh24mmss')` gives me a wrong Date

01.03.2018

`select TO_TIMESTAMP(qtime,'hh24mmss')` gives me a wrong Date

01.03.2018 **BUT** the correct time with f.e. **15:20:15**,0000000

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated

Note: I only have reading rights on the database Oracle 12c, so I need to to this within Statements

Comment: Since you are creating a DATE type, and did not include a y/m/d component,  Oracle will supply a default.  What do you really want to set the m/d/y for what value

Comment: Can you please provide a full example.  We need to see your two input values - one date and one time - in their original format.  Then could you walk through the logic that you expect to be applied?  I think you'll get more help that way

Comment: Difference of two times is meaningless without using the date  (day component) alongside it. If you are finding the difference of 15:20:15 with 08:20:15, how will you know if it is today's 08:20 or tomorrow's?

Comment: The Database contains another column with the correct date for each time. For the qtime there is a corresponding field in the data entry with the qdate (201800102). I don't know if it's possible to extract this entry into a converting operation.

Comment: select EXTRACT( hour from ( TO_DATE(qtime, 'hh24miss') - TO_DATE(ztime, 'hh24miss') ) day to second ) from dual;

Comment: If the database has fields that represent the correct dates, why don't you use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "The Database contains another column with the correct date for each time"

The missing piece of the puzzle! Concatenate the two columns to get something which can be converted to an Oracle DATE:

```
select to_date(qdate||qtime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') as qdatetime
       , to_date(zdate||ztime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') as zdatetime
from your_table
```

Once you have done that you can perform arithmetic of the dates e.g.

```
select id
       , zdatetime - qdatetime as time_diff
from (  select id
               , to_date(qdate||qtime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') as qdatetime
               , to_date(zdate||ztime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') as zdatetime
      from your_table
)
```

If you want the number of hours in the difference you can include this expression in the projection of the outer query:

```
, extract( hour from (zdatetime - qdatetime) day to second) as hrs_ela
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much. I'll try to get a workaround with this help. Sorry I am pretty new into Oracle SQL development.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you are trying to convert a varchar2 into a date without specifying neither day nor month, it will default to the first day of the current month:

> If you specify a date value without a date, then the default date is the first day of the current month.

You can read up more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#GUID-4D95F6B2-8F28-458A-820D-6C05F848CA23)

Also in 2nd and 3rd your example, you are using 'hh24mmss' for specifying hour, minute and second components, but do note that correct format for minutes is **'mi'** and not 'mm', which is used for months.

So the solution is to concatenate both date and time component when creating the date as the other answer suggested, tho I would recommend using a single date field as it can store the information you need.